# Evaluating $\oint_C (\arctan{y} - 5y)dx + \left(\frac{x}{1+y^2} + 2x\right)dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate integral of

$$\oint_C (\arctan{y} - 5y)dx + \left(\frac{x}{1+y^2} + 2x\right)dy$$

where $C$ is the ellipse $x^2/16 + y^2/25 = 1$.

So I used the Green's Theorem and got double integral of $D$ of $7 \; dy\; dx$. What do I do now? How do I get the $x$ and $y$ bounds? Please show steps to how to solve this using Green's Theorem. Please don't use some crazy methods to solve it. I just want to keep it simple. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Now that you are at: $$\iint_{D}7dydx=7\iint_{D}dydx$$you actually don't need to worry about the integration limits. It turns out that: $$\iint_{D}1dxdy=(\mbox{Area of }D). $$ So you just need to get the area of that ellipse.

Comment: Could you finish up for me please? That's what I am stuck on...

Comment: There is a nice little formula for the area of an ellipse.  If $a$ is half the length of the major axis and $b$ is half the length of the minor axis, then the area is $\pi ab$.

Comment: Then I can just use that?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to argue geometrically, using the area of ellipse, use Green's formula *twice* (for double credit?)

$$\iint_D 7\,dx\,dy  = \oint_C \frac{7}{2}(-y\,dx+x\,dy) $$
and use the parametric equation $x=4\cos t$, $y=5\sin t$  to finish it off: 
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{7}{2}(-5\sin t \cdot (-4\sin t) +4\cos t\cdot 5\cos t) \,dt
$$
where the integrand simplifies *a lot*.